# 12-column CSS grid system similar to Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a 12-column CSS grid system very similar to Bootstrap. 4 breakpoints are supported: `normal, sm, md, and lg`. Anyway, here is the code:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.row [class^="col-"] {
    float: left;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
[class^="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 577px) {
    .col-sm-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-sm-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 993px) {
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
    }
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
    }
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate a review of this code. So far, I have no problems in my testing. It is also meant to support IE11.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using flexbox or css grid?

Comment: @gview Yes, I wanted to support IE11, and flex-box has some weird bugs that randomly popup on that browser.

Comment: Are you using plain CSS or generating this code dynamically using some preprocessor language like SCSS?

Comment: @MohammadUsman Plain old CSS

Comment: https://learncssgrid.com

Comment: Honestly, I've seen much worse. There may be some constructs available to make this even cleaner, but it's fairly straight-forward.